# Change module from manual to composer installed

Tags: 8, composer

Note: This is not a duplicate of [The site has a mix of modules installed manually and via Composer: Can I move all to Composer?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253072)
As this question below involves different folder locations.

I currently have modules installed via the Drupal UI (/admin/modules/install) which have installed in the directory /modules.

And I also have composer installed modules which are added to the directory /modules/contrib

**Task:** To move modules over to Composer managed.

I have run "composer require drupal/MODULE" which has put the module in the /modules/contrib location. But now there are 2 copies and upon refresh & clear cache, Drupal is still using the old module location. (I can tell as the composer installed module is a newer version)

I would prefer not to have to uninstall all the modules that need moving as it can cause issues.

I have tried just removing the module from directory /modules (leaving the new composer installed module in modules/contrib), but I get the WSOD.

**Question:** How do I switch modules over to Composer managed with a different directory location?

Comment: Just delete the old module folders and rebuild caches, everything else will take care of itself

Comment: Try drush updb after deleting modules